# Is there a way to let the button color remain unchanged after changing/switching screen?

Tags: python, kivy

What I'm trying to achieve here is to change the color button in the SurveyHeader widget after clicking either checkboxes. Example: after checking any checkboxes in question 3, I would like only button number "3" to turn red. Also, after clicking next, I would like the button number "3" to remain red. This is where I'm having a hard time., after switching screens, my button color changes to the original color. Is it because I'm creating a new instance of QuestionsScreen1 everytime? If so, is there any workaround for my case?

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition, WipeTransition, NoTransition, SlideTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
import re

class NavTray1(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SurveyHeader(GridLayout):
    pass

class SubjectsLayout(GridLayout):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class BeginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class QuestionsScreen1(Screen):
    def insert_data_A(self, *args):
        if args[1] == True:
            pass

    def insert_data_B(self, *args):
        self.question_text1 = MDApp.get_running_app().root.current
        if args[1] == True:
            pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    # Create new page from 1 to 5.
    def new_page(self):
        if self.current == 'begin':
            s = QuestionsScreen1(name='Question 1')
            if "Question 1" in self.screen_names:
                self.current = 'Question 1'
            else:
                self.add_widget(s)
                self.current = 'Question 1'
        elif self.current =='Question 5':
            pass
        else:
            current_page_number = int(re.search(r'\d+', self.current).group(0))
            s = QuestionsScreen1(name='Question {}'.format(str(int(current_page_number +1))))
            if "Question {}".format(str(int(current_page_number +1))) in self.screen_names:
                self.current = 'Question {}'.format(str(int(current_page_number +1)))
            else:
                self.add_widget(s)
                self.current = 'Question {}'.format(str(int(current_page_number + 1)))
    # Switch screens according to number.
    def switch_pages(self, instance):
        question_button = StringProperty()
        self.question_button = instance.text
        s = QuestionsScreen1(name='Question {}'.format(self.question_button))
        if 'Question {}'.format(self.question_button) in self.screen_names:
            self.current = 'Question {}'.format(self.question_button)
        else:
            self.add_widget(s)
            self.current = 'Question {}'.format(self.question_button)
    # Switch screens between 1 to 5.
    def back_page(self):
        current_page = StringProperty()
        if self.current == 'Question 1':
            pass
        else:
            current_page_number = int(re.search(r'\d+', self.current).group(0))
            s = QuestionsScreen1(name='Question {}'.format(str(int(current_page_number -1))))
            if "Question {}".format(str(int(current_page_number -1))) in self.screen_names:
                self.current = 'Question {}'.format(str(int(current_page_number - 1)))
            else:
                self.add_widget(s)
                self.current = 'Question {}'.format(str(int(current_page_number - 1)))

main_widget_kv = ('''
#: import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect

MyScreenManager:
    BeginScreen:

<BeginScreen>:
    begin_button:begin_button
    name: "begin"
    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgb: .1, .1, .1
    FloatLayout:
        id: begin_layout
        Button:
            id: begin_button
            text: 'Begin'
            font_size: 24
            on_press: app.root.new_page()
            size_hint: (.4,.25)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.2}
            color: [0,0,0,1]

<NavTray1>:
    cols: 3
    padding: '5dp'
    spacing: '5dp'
    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgb: .1, .1, .1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    MDRaisedButton:
        size_hint_x: None
        color: [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1]
        font_style: 'Body1'
        height: dp(80)
        text: 'Back'
        on_release : app.root.back_page()
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_x: 0.4
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            font_style: 'Body1'
    MDRaisedButton:
        size_hint_x: None
        color: [6/255, 114/255, 0, 1]
        height: dp(80)
        text: "Next"
        font_style: 'Body1'
        background_color: [28/138, 1, 35/138, 0.5]
        on_release : app.root.new_page()

<QuestionsScreen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        SurveyHeader:
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            height: '90dp'
            id: header
            rows: 2
            Button:
                text: "1"
                background_color: [0,255,255,1]
                on_release: app.root.switch_pages(self)
            Button:
                text: "2"
                background_color: [0,255,255,1]
                on_release: app.root.switch_pages(self)
            Button:
                text: "3"
                background_color: [0,255,255,1]
                on_release: app.root.switch_pages(self)
            Button:
                text: "4"
                background_color: [0,255,255,1]
                on_release: app.root.switch_pages(self)
            Button:
                text: "5"
                background_color: [0,255,255,1]
                on_release: app.root.switch_pages(self)
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            height: root.height - header.height - navtray.height
            SubjectsLayout:
                cols: 1
                Label:
                    size_hint_y : 0.25
                    text: app.root.current
                    text_size: self.size
                    valign: 'middle'
                    halign: 'center'
                GridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    rows: 2
                    size_hint_y : 0.75
                    Label:
                        text: 'a'
                        font_size: "20dp" 
                        size_hint_x : 0.8
                    CheckBox:
                        group: 'answer_group'
                        size_hint_x : 0.2
                        on_active: root.insert_data_A(*args)
                    Label:
                        text: 'b'
                        font_size: "20dp"
                        size_hint_x : 0.8
                    CheckBox:
                        group: 'answer_group'
                        size_hint_x : 0.2
                        on_active: root.insert_data_B(*args)
        NavTray1:
            id: navtray
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            height: '90dp'


''')

class TestApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        main_widget = Builder.load_string(main_widget_kv)
        return main_widget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal executeable example ... reference to MDApp is missing

Comment: oh sorry, because it is kivymd, so I had to use MDApp

Comment: Ok, installed kivymd .. I miss that you store your values. And that you make changes depending on the status.

Comment: I would suggest making the question a property of the `QuestionsScreen1` `Screen`, rather than the name. Then, in your `main_widget_kv`, you could just add `QuestionsScreen1` as another child of `MyScreenManager`. Then you never need to create a new `QuestionsScreen1`, just change that question property. That way, your `Buttons` will not change color when you go to the next question. This will require many changes to your code, but I think it is a better approach.